# Is there a way to intercept a Kafka ProducerRecord after it has been serialized?

Tags: apache-kafka

[Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html) for `ProducerInterceptor`'s `onSend` method says:

> This is called from KafkaProducer.send(ProducerRecord) and KafkaProducer.send(ProducerRecord, Callback) methods, before key and value get serialized and partition is assigned (if partition is not specified in ProducerRecord).

Is there a way to intercept the `ProducerRecord` after the key and value have been serialized?

Comment: What's the use case for needing two byte arrays?

Comment: I want to change the way it is serialized so that it uses one serialization approach within a KStreams app (and its state stores) and another outside/on the topics.

Comment: If you want to change that, just define your own Serde or use map function

Comment: A Serde isn't aware of the context it's called in (ie. putting/getting from a state store vs. producing/consuming). Ideally there are two Serdes (one for producing/consuming and another for putting/getting from a state store). I haven't tried map yet, but did try transformValues with a KTable and did not work well -- [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907132/using-kafka-streams-with-serdes-that-rely-on-schema-references-in-the-headers)